# Turkish visa processing still ongoing after the date of my intended trip has passed. What can I do?

Tags: visas, turkey

I applied for a Turkish tourist visa here at the embassy as I was not eligible for e-Visa. The problem is that hotel arrangements and flight schedules that I provided have already expired and yet the embassy says it will take 9 more days to issue the visa.

It is recommended that you apply for a visa 15 days before arrival. I applied just 5 days in advance because of an urgent plan. They've accepted the application, but now I am clueless whether or not they will approve or reject my visa. What steps can I take to finalize the visa issuance process?

Comment: I don't know about Turkey but at this point your trip is ruined anyway and, if at all possible, it might be best to pull your application to avoid the prejudice of a negative decision. Any fee you have paid is probably lost as well.

Comment: Depending on the urgency and the situation though, you could conceivably rebook a hotel and flight for a later date and still go if they issue the visa. You "only" lose money but might still be able to make it

Comment: In case you are rejected, keep in mind that some airlines will allow refunds on preferred terms (perhaps even free) if you provide an official visa rejection letter from a consulate. This isn't always the case (check your fare rules), but it does happen, e.g. I've seen it in fare rules of some flights from Russia, even some European airlines serving Russia... could be the same for Turkey.

Answer (score 2):

At this point one thing is certain, your trip is ruined, but you have a few options left.

**Option 1**
You can decide to pull your application to avoid receiving a negative decision as that can influence future visa applications. The visa fee you paid is lost.

**Option 2**
Depending on your airline and seat fare purchased, some airlines allow refunds (perhaps with a fee though) if you provide an official rejection letter from a consulate.

**Option 3**
The last option, depending on how Turkish visas are processed and in the case you might still be issued a visa is to rebook your hotel and flight and simply go at a later date. This is possibly the most expensive option, but you still get to travel to Turkey